# Removing the dot or period from htaccess files - A dangerous move?

Tags: htaccess

Removing the dot or period from htaccess files (and thus making it unhidden) - A dangerous move?

I tried to search in Google with the string: `Can I remove the dot htaccess` But I didn't find anything directly related to this question.

The reason for removing it is one and simple --- To edit it faster directly from the FTP client instead of navigating to the Cpanel file manager...

Comment: You can remove the dot *or* the period, but not both. Make sure you leave at least one of them otherwise the file will no longer work as intended.

Comment: My guess is that if '.htaccess' becomes 'htaccess', it will be visible on 'domain.com/htaccess'. If Apache works like standard Linux does, changing to 'htaccess' is possible as you would just need a symbolic link with '.htacces' pointing at the visible file. However I highly suspect it will be visible to all. As to what the security implications of this are - well, I don't know. Setting up the server and ftp/sftp client properly so that you see hidden files would possibly be the better choice as others indicated.

Comment: This is just wrong. The dot *is* the period.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's dangerous in the sense that it won't work if you do. Apache will look for `.htaccess` and apply those rules as it serves content. Without finding that file, Apache will proceed assuming no additional directives are necessary.

`.htaccess` includes a leading `.` because it's a "hidden file" in Linux systems (which run most web servers).

Comment: And yes, as @FiascoLabs mentioned, you should be able to set your FTP client to show hidden files if you regularly need to edit that. There will sometimes be a setting called "LIST parameters" where you can add `-al` to show them.

Comment: FWIW you can change the name of the file that Apache looks for with the `AccessFileName` directive (which _defaults_ to `.htaccess`).

Comment: Yes, but only if you have access to the Apache config. I presumed this was a shared hosting platform based on the cPanel mention.

Comment: And server changes made for trivial reasons often have unintended consequences down the line. Changing the hidden file view in a client is more appropriate.

Comment: You can use a symbolic link to `.htaccess` if you want to serve it. Then you can control the name and location.

Comment: To be clear, a dot at the beginning of a filename makes it a hidden file on all *Unix* systems, not just on Linux systems. It makes the filename hidden on everything that isn’t Windows.

Answer (score 8):

Your FTP client has a setting to show hidden files. Turn it on. Or use a client that allows `.` hidden files to be seen.

And use SFTP as FTP sends clear-text credentials (clear-text => unencrypted as in you can retrieve them by running tcpdump or similar traffic analysis and capturing the packets).

Comment: The FTP server might be the one doing the hiding, in which case client settings will have no effect.

Answer (score 5):

> Removing the dot or period from htaccess files and thus making it unhidden - A dangerous move?

You definitely have to be careful how you do it, as you might otherwise compromise the security of your server.

There are basically two dangers that you could encounter:

**Reading your htaccess File**

htaccess files are nothing special, and if you just rename `.htaccess` to `htaccess`, anyone can now read it, as it will be served as a normal file by Apache. It doesn't matter here if you changed `AccessFileName` or not. Access to `.htaccess` is denied by these lines in your Apache config, which will not catch htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

This may have negative consequences, such as leaking of information. Your htaccess file may for example contain absolute paths, and possibly other sensitive information such as [database passwords defined via SetEnv](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13772).

**htaccess File not working**

Of course, if you rename your `.htaccess` file, it will not be parsed anymore. This means that you have to change `AccessFileName`.

But if you just change `AccessFileName .htaccess` to `AccessFileName htaccess`, this might be dangerous, as some other applications on the same server may rely on .htaccess files being parsed. There are quite a few applications whose security heavily relies on `.htaccess` files being parsed properly, for example because it denies access to files containing passwords, uploaded PHP files, etc (relying on .htaccess files being parsed isn't ideal, but it does happen frequently).

**Doing it right: Adding additional .htaccess file names**

If you want to rename your .htaccess file, you have to do two things:

Add the new name to `AccessFileName` (do not remove the default .htaccess name):

```
AccessFileName .htaccess htaccess
```

And add a deny rule for it:

```
<FilesMatch "^htaccess">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

<sub>[it isn't quite clear to me if you want to rename your htaccess file permanently or just temporarily while editing it, but the dangers I described above apply in either case, as does the solution proposed]</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Removing the dot is **renaming** the file.
Once you do that, the web server won't be able to find the file, so its contents will no-longer effect web server behavior.

If after considering all the disadvantages of running a non-standard set-up you  you still want to rename, it you can configure apache to look for the file under a different name, but it may make sense to make the name clearly different to `.htaccess`

eg: to change it to `www.config`  add this to your web-server's configuration:

```
AccessFileName www.config
```

However the apache documentation recommends not using `.htaccess` at all, and doing all configuration in the server configuration file.

Comment: Make sure you include instructions on how to block access from the renamed .htaccess file from being served out by the webserver. Security conscious hosting providers often block `.htaccess` from being readable by web clients.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not do this. It is dangerous, incorrect, and the wrong answer to the problem.

1. If you remove the dot, it changes it to a different filename. Apache is programmed specifically to look for the filename with the dot, so it won't see your renamed file as being anything special. Your server config commands in the file won't get loaded, and your site probably won't work as intended. This can be worked around by making changes to the core Apache config, but obviously only if you have access to it (which you probably don't if you're on shared hosting), but in general it's best not to change that kind of thing.
2. If you remove the dot, then the file will become accessible to web browsers, thus making key parts of your server config visible to hackers and potentially giving them information that will help them attack you. It is possible to work around this and make sure the file remains hidden, but that involves further messing around in the main server config.
3. Your FTP client will have a setting that allows you to see hidden files. (if it doesn't, get yourself a better FTP client!)
4. While we're talking about FTP -- don't use it. Always use SFTP instead. the "S" stands for "Secure". If you're using FTP without the 'S', you're not secure. (unbelievably, there are some web hosting companies that only give you FTP access, not SFTP. If you're on one of them, find a better hosting company as soon as you can).

Answer (score 0):

Your web host ( or Apache server ) will not be able to detect it is a ".htaccess" file, instead, it will see it as a file with no extension.

So, I wouldn't say its DANGEROUS, but it certainly would not operate correctly, or at all.